# CSS/SCSS: Is there a way to 'reset' a property to that set in a previous class?

Tags: css, sass

On framework.scss I have:

```
.row {
  margin: $margin-variable;
}
```

On page.scss I have

```
.row {
  margin: auto;
}
```

I have a new scss file, mobile-page.scss, that overwrites page.scss with a media query. I want mobile-page' `.row`s margin to inherit whatever `$margin-variable` is.

Is there a way I can tell margin to ignore the value set on page.scss and inherit that which is on framework.scss?

Comment: Why are you declaring the same thing in each file?

Comment: @pol how do you mean? framework.scss came with the framework and I don't want to alter the file directly. page.scss is me styling the .row on my page and mobile-page.scss is the mobile variant of that page.

Comment: I think you only need two SCSS files: one for "default" per se, and another one for "mobile" per se. Obviously, `mobile-page.scss` is for your mobile. Now, you'll have to choose which one to use as your "default": `framework.scss` or `page.scss`. Having all three of them only makes things complicated.

Comment: just use margin: $margin-variable;

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this, both should be in your page.scss not the framework.scss as I assume the framework file are your default framework classes. page.scss also must be loaded after framework.scss in order to successfully override framework's classes:

1. Override the class inside itself to override it at a certain breakpoint (can be max, min, or a combination of max and min):

```css
.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  @media screen and (max-width: $your-margin-variable) {
    margin: $something-else;
  }
}
```

2. Use specificity to put your media query in the row class at the end of all your css so it overrides the one further up above:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: $your-margin-variable) {
  .row {
     margin: $something-else;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on mobile.scss use

```
.row{
     margin: $margin-variable;
}
```

Don't forget to add this stylesheet after the framework stylesheets.